# Will a 307 redirect to a 503 error page during a six hour maintenance window affect SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects, site-maintenance

I run a pretty high-traffic ecommerce site. There's going to be a period of time when a 3rd-party service will be unavailable for scheduled maintenance, which will make most of my site inoperable.

My plan to avoid confusion for customers is to just do a 307 redirect to a maintenance page when someone visits the site (on any page).

My main concern is, can this affect SEO if it's a 6-hour block of time?

And my other question is, on the maintenance page, would it look odd to search engines if i have a noindex robots tag on it, like this?

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>
```

I know Google recommends a 503, but I'm redirecting to a maintenance page, rather than returning a different homepage. So my plan would be a 307 (on all pages), to a maintenance page that uses a 503.

Comment: Why do you want to redirect to the maintenance page rather than return the 503 error more directly?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Seemed less drastic than replacing the homepage. Would it be better to replace the homepage with the contents of my maintenance page (which would have a 503 header)?

Comment: A custom 503 doesn't typically "replace the homepage."  You would typically add something temporarily to your `.htaccess` or web server config files to show the error for every page on your site, including the home page.   See [How can I return a 503 status in apache without invoking external scripts](https://serverfault.com/questions/53061/how-can-i-return-a-503-status-in-apache-without-invoking-external-scripts)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks. Rather than the redirect I'm simply going to load a new page template that sends a 503 status code. This template would show on all pages. Should I bother adding the noindex tag would that be asking for trouble?

Comment: Google doesn't index error pages so `noindex` isn't needed.  I wouldn't include it in case it confused anything.